# C# thread lock failed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two working threads.I have locked both with a same lock, but threadB is getting executed before threadA, so exception came.I locked both using the same lock object.Thread B is using delegate function.How can I solve the issue.

Detailed Information:

---

I have a class called `StateSimulation`.
Inside that there are two functions called
              a) `OnSimulationCollisionReset`
              b) `OnSimulationProgressEvent`

Implementation is like this:

```
private void OnSimulationCollisionReset()
{
    Thread XmlReset = new Thread(XmlResetFn);
    XmlReset.Start();
}

private void OnSimulationProgressEvent()
{
    DataStoreSingleTon.Instance.IsResetCompleted = true;
    Thread ThrdSimulnProgress = new Thread(SimulnProgress);
    ThrdSimulnProgress.Start();
}
```

where `SimulnProgress()` and `XmlResetFn()` are as follows:

```
private void SimulnProgress()
{
    //uses a delegate 
    UIControlHandler.Instance.ShowSimulationProgress();
}

private void XmlResetFn()
{
    DataStoreSingleTon.Instance.GetFPBConfigurationInstance().ResetXmlAfterCollision();
}
```

In which `OnSimulationProgressEvent()` is using a delegate function.

Both `showSimulationProgress` and `ResetXML...()` uses a same resource `FPBArrayList`.

My requirement is `SimulationProgressEvent()` should work only after `Reset..()`. In `resetXML..()` I clear the `FPBList`.
In `SimulationProgress()` I access `FPBList[i]` where `i:0--->size;`
I have locked both functions using a same lock object.I expected, `reset()` will complete first. But after entering to reset, before complete reset, `showProgress()` started and exception occured..

How to solve my issue?

This is how I locked the functions

```
public System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();

private void SimulnProgress()
{
    lock (lockThis)
    {
        UIControlHandler.Instance.ShowSimulationProgress();
    }
}

private void XmlResetFn()
{
    lock (lockThis)
    {
        DataStoreSingleTon.Instance.GetFPBConfigurationInstance().ResetXmlAfterCollision();
    }
}
```

Please give a solution.
Regards
Nidhin KR

Comment: Please format your code better, hard to follow it. You might have to redesign the app a bit.

Comment: What exception is it that is thrown?

Answer (score 2):

Locks are intended to prevent several threads from entering a given section of code simultaneously. They are not intended to synchronize the threads in any other way, like, making them execute code in some specific order.

To enforce the execution order you need to implement some signalling between your threads.
Have a look at [Synchronization Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), specifically, [Auto/ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksb7zs2x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to write multithreaded code that assumes or requires that execution on different threads occurs in a particular order.  The whole point of multithreading is to allow things to be executed *independently* of each other.  Independently means no particular order is expressed or implied.  CPU time might not be distributed evenly between the two threads, for example, particularly is one thread is waiting for an external signaling event and the other thread is in a compute loop.

For your particular code, it seems very odd that `IsResetCompleted = true;` is set in the OnSimulationProgressEvent handler.  The completion state of the Reset activity should be set by the Reset activity, not by some other event executing in another thread assuming "If we're here, the work in the other thread must be finished."

You should review your design and identify your assumptions and dependencies between threads.  If thread B must not proceed until after thread A has completed something, you should first reexamine why you're putting this work in different threads, and then perhaps use a synchronization object (such as an AutoResetEvent) to coordinate between the threads.

The key point here is if you take a sequential task and split it into multiple threads, but the threads use locks or synch objects to serialize their execution, then there is no benefit to using multiple threads.  The operation is still sequential.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand the question entirely, but if your requirement is simply that you want to prevent the body of `SimulnProgress` from executing before `XmlResetfn` has executed at least once, you can do:

```
public readonly object lockThis = new object();
private readonly ManualResetEvent resetHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void SimulnProgress()
{
    resetHandle.WaitOne();

    lock (lockThis)
    {
        UIControlHandler.Instance.ShowSimulationProgress();
    }
}

private void XmlResetFn()
{
    lock (lockThis)
    {
        DataStoreSingleTon.Instance.GetFPBConfigurationInstance().ResetXmlAfterCollision();
    }

    resetHandle.Set();
}
```